# Plugin develop and Xtext: extends ViewPart and doesn't know how to get the AST of the active file

Tags: eclipse, plugins, xtext

I am developing a new plugin for my dsl language (that I used xtext for developing it). In my plugin, I want that for every *.mydsl file, it's should view graph of vars that define in the file that open.

For that, I need to get some EObject that define in the open file.
If I would have some EObject, I can travel the AST to get all the vars I need for the graph.

So, I extends ViewPart class, and I tried to find the current file that open in this code:

```
  IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
```

But, I don't know how to get from IWorkbenchPage some EObject type, can someone tell me how I can do it? (or another way that will work)

**--------UPDATE:---------**

**I found it hard to go over the AST of the file by getting EObject (because I wanted to use functions like: EcoreUtil2.getContainerOfType(context, Model)
and it's work only in the xtext project.)
Instead of finding EObject, is there a way to get the AST of the file? I want all vars of specific types that define in the active file. (The file in the current tab)
Thanks!**

Comment: The IWorkbenchPage contains all the views and editors currently open on the page, the page doesn't have an input file. You will need to find the active editor and find a way to get what you want from that.

Comment: Thanks!! This is what I did  `IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
          IEditorPart activeEditor = page.getActiveEditor();` How can I get the AST of the file? or all the vars of specific types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEditorPart activeEditor = page.getActiveEditor();
if (activeEditor instanceof XtextEditor) {
    XtextEditor xtextEditor = (XtextEditor) activeEditor;
    xtextEditor.getDocument().readOnly((XtextResource resource) -> {
        EObject content = resource.getContents().get(0);
        // Do your AST related stuff here
        ...

        // Optionally return a result
        return null;
    });
}
```

Comment: You know if there is method like: `EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(p, Var)` that I can use? or if there is a way I can use this method in my plugin? ( I used it for develop mydsl language). This line: `EObject content = resource.getContents().get(0);` return EObject from the active file, it's good!!! But, I don't know how to go over the AST, I didn't found a way.

Comment: If you want to search the whole content for instances of a specific type, you could use the iterator returned by `content.eAllContents()` and filter by the type you're looking for.